# Windows CRYPT32 CertFreeCertificateChainEngine removes user certificate from trusted root authority

Tags: windows, ssl, ssl-certificate

I add the user certificate to Trusted CA (e.g. certificate of HandyCache application).
Then use an **another** application, which initializes CertificateChainEngine and checks certificates on encrypted connections, the code of initialization is the following:

```
CERT_CHAIN_ENGINE_CONFIG config = { sizeof(config) };
config.dwFlags = CERT_CHAIN_CACHE_END_CERT;
HCERTCHAINENGINE engine;
::CertCreateCertificateChainEngine(&config, &engine);
```

After some work, I close an application, and the engine is destroyed with:

```
::CertFreeCertificateChainEngine
```

There is a strange behaviour inside this function: the mentioned user certificate is deleted from Trusted CA during the call, the stack is the following:

```
CRYPT32!RegDeleteKeyExW
CRYPT32!ILS_DeleteElementFromRegistry+0x4e
CRYPT32!ShipAssertUserRootStoreCertificateAddition+0x13d
CRYPT32!IPR_DeleteUnprotectedRootsFromStore+0x8e
CRYPT32!ResyncFromRegistry+0xdc
CRYPT32!RegistryNotifyChange+0x38
CRYPT32!RegStoreProvControl+0x8e
CRYPT32!CertControlStore+0x4c
CRYPT32!ControlCollectionStore+0x61
CRYPT32!CertControlStore+0x2c
CRYPT32!ControlCollectionStore+0x61
CRYPT32!CertControlStore+0x2c
CRYPT32!CCertChainEngine::~CCertChainEngine+0xf9
CRYPT32!CCertChainEngine::`scalar deleting destructor'+0xd
CRYPT32!CCertChainEngine::Release+0x1d
CRYPT32!CertFreeCertificateChainEngine+0x23
```

The user certificate is deleted inside CRYPT32!RegDeleteKeyExW. 
So, I have a questions:
Why CertFreeCertificateChainEngine can decide to delete all custom certificates from user Trusted CA storage? 
Any ideas of undocumented initialization flags, which can control this behaviour?

UPD: Reproduced on Windows 7 and Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch ::CertCreateCertificateChainEngine in IE in debugger, discover, that IE uses the following initialization flags:

```
0x30 // CERT_CHAIN_ENABLE_CACHE_AUTO_UPDATE | CERT_CHAIN_ENABLE_SHARE_STORE
```

After changing flags in the problem application to

```
config.dwFlags = CERT_CHAIN_CACHE_END_CERT | 
CERT_CHAIN_ENABLE_CACHE_AUTO_UPDATE | CERT_CHAIN_ENABLE_SHARE_STORE;
```

the users certificates from Trusted CA are **not deleted** anymore on engine free. 
Don't know, why these flags absence affects to certificates deletion.